# Is it possible to "isolate" my bootstrap .js function from other bootstrap version?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

hope someone can help me. I need to add a javascript to multiple websites. And some of this websites have bootstrap, some don't. Some are using bootstrap 3 some 4. And one has also a customised version of bootstrap, where some function are modified.
I'm using bootstrap 4 and with SASS you can set a prefix for the bootstrap.css file. And this works fine. But how can I ensure that my bootstrap version is not overriding another bootstrap?
Is there a way to isolate the bootstrap.js?

Thanks.